# If Google Chrome displays XML file with no errors - can I suppose that this file is valid?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm struggling with submitting sitemap to Google and Webmaster Tools indicating some errors. Nevertheless after some improvements Google Chrome browser now displays the sitemap XML files with no errors messages. Can I use this as the indication that I have good sitemap file (in this case I will suppose that Google need more time to reconsider sitemap)?

I placed this question in this section purposely as this question more related to programming not site mastering.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome (or another browser) displays an XML file w/o errors, this means that its internal *XML structure* is valid. But this do not guarantee that you have a valid *sitemap*.

Comment: Hi, @Oleg! Thank you for contribution to the topic! I'd like to make a bit clear my question. XML image sitemap uses `<image:image>` tags to indicate the image record which generates error messages in Chrome until you add `xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"` attribute in the `<urlset>` tag.